What Features Should I Look for When Buying My First Track Saw?
I was hoping to get some advice on the features I should look for in a good track saw, especially are there any must-have accessories or options I should consider?

Note that you are asking multiple questions in one, which is not in line with the format of this site. I still tried to provide a broad answer. As for recommending specific saws, shopping questions are out of scope here :)

My question to you would be why do you think you need a tracksaw? It's not the functionality of the tool that I'm asking about, but the perceived need for a formal track saw for that, when e.g. a very good direct equivalent can be had (usually much cheaper) starting with a circular saw. Or alternatively, working in a different way entirely — realise that there's a huge number of woodworkers who haven't got a tracksaw OR or a circular saw, OR a table saw and they aren't enviously eyeing any one of those three tools and wishing they had them. Many many ways to skin any cat.

My 2¢, as mentioned in my answer, a circular saw with a guide has much worse dust collection (which is to say, none at all). Track saw’s dust collection is really good, way better than most table saws and miter saws. The premium price is for the combination of portability+accuracy+cleanliness. Which is why these are popular with and primarily marketed to installers and site carpenters. Agree that not everyone needs one. I have since switched to mostly hand tools and can see getting by with just that, but I do still use my track saw for material breakdown, because it’s quick and non-dirty :)

@stanch, good dust collection is undeniably its own reward in the right contexts. However, in line with the need/perceived need for a track saw in the first place, some users and working setups simply don't require dust collection, period. Plenty of guys do breakdown cuts of sheet goods primarily on their driveway for instance.

I strongly recommend you watch Peter Millard’s track saw playlists on YouTube as he covers all of this.
I will answer from my perspective: I have been using a corded Makita track saw for 3 years and this is the only power saw I have (no table saw or miter saw).
There is some subjectivity to your questions, but I would say one objective thing to look for is rail compatibility (also covered by Peter Millard). Ideally, you want a saw whose rail accepts the common accessories (so Festool, Makita, etc), although some accessory manufacturers are now making stuff for less common rails (e.g. DeWalt). Using a common rail also means you have more options (and often, more affordable ones) for buying shorter/longer rails as needed.
Other features to consider are the effectiveness of dust collection (one of the main reasons to buy a track saw and not make a DIY track for a circular saw), blade size, riving knife (and/or electric brake), ease of depth adjustment. You also need to decide between corded and cordless.
The most useful accessory is a track square, which gives you instant accurate square cuts. Parallel guides are great for cutting long sheets or boards to width. I really like the TSO square and guides because one of the guides attaches to the square. Essentially, you get a square with a ruler, allowing you to accurately cross-cut to length. TSO stuff is very expensive, but my reasoning was that I didn’t have space for table/miter saws, so I wanted maximum versatility from the track saw. Since I’ve bought these, much cheaper versions have appeared on BangGood (some of them are original designs), which you might want to check.
The second most useful accessory is a good blade. My Makita came with a 40-tooth blade and was struggling with rips. A combination blade made a huge difference.
Third, track clamps — a must have for bigger, thicker pieces of wood where the track might slip from cutting resistance.
There is a whole world of MFTs, perforated surfaces and bench dogs, but I decided early on I didn’t want the accuracy to come from the surface, which is really a consumable. Also, MDF would definitely swell in my shop. Your mileage may vary.
Arbor hole cover is nice to have and cuts down on dust a lot. There are many 3d-printed options on Etsy. Or you can just tape it off for free (does not look as good though).

Superb, extra +1 if I could!

Side note about joining short rails into a long rail: I found this fussy and awkward, so went straight to having a long track and a short track. Granted, this isn’t cheap.

@AloysiusDefenestrate At least for Festool/Makita rails, there are self-aligning connectors that supposedly work better. But they cost more, so in the end long rails probably make more sense. I hear other rails have a better extension story (Bosch/Mafell?). Or you can move the rail a few times, aligning as best as possible (parallel guides actually help with this), and then pass over the edge with a jointer plane.

Should have noted that my experience is in the dewalt universe. (I’m committed to their battery ecosystem, and it would be a really big deal for me to go corded or to a different platform.)
